# Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined in Salesforce

Tags: jquery, salesforce, visualforce

I am trying to get data from a list and sorting it by using jQuery but for this I'm getting this error on console.

> Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined on Console.

If I add static data it is working. I am new to jQuery.

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" controller="PaginationCon">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

 <script type="text/javascript">

             $(function () {
            $("#example1").dataTable();            
        });          

    </script>

  <apex:form >
       <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>BodyLength</th>
                <th>Created Date</th>
                <th>Owner Name</th>
                <th>Click To View</th>
            </tr>

        </thead>

        <tbody>
           <apex:repeat value="{!att}" var="at">
<tr>
    <td> <apex:outputText value="{!at.Name}"/></td>
    <td> <apex:outputText value="{!at.BodyLength}"/></td>
    <td> <apex:outputText value="{!at.CreatedDate}"/></td>
    <td> <apex:outputText value="{!at.Owner.Name}"/></td>
    <td> <apex:commandLink value="View"/></td>
    <td> <apex:commandLink value="Delete"/></td>      
</tr>
  </apex:repeat>
 </tbody>

    </table>

  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class PaginationCon {

    public List<Attachment> att{get;set;}

    public PaginationCon ()
    {
        att=new List<Attachment>();
        att=[select id,Name,BodyLength,CreatedDate,Owner.Name from Attachment limit 1000];
    }
}
```

Comment: I think datatable() requires same number of columns in tbody and thead. You have 5 columns in header and 6 in body... Please test after removing the "delete td" --- or add another td in thead section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this element below "Click to View" Table Header

```
<th>Click To Delete</th>
```

it should be this now.

```
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>BodyLength</th>
    <th>Created Date</th>
    <th>Owner Name</th>
    <th>Click To View</th>
    <th>Click To Delete</th>
</tr>
</thead>
```

`<thead>` and `<tbody>` should have the same number of columns.